# Destroying prefab with line renderer doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a empty gameobject and attach a script to create a line using linerenderer. Then made it as prefab. After that I instantiated that prefab using this code

```
GameObject lines = (GameObject)Instantiate(screenlines,new Vector3 ( 
    spawnerObjPos.transform.localPosition.x, listoflines[testt], 
    spawnerObjPos.transform.localPosition.z), transform.rotation);
Destroy(lines , 5);
```

After that I Destroyed that GameObject . My problem is after destroying the GameObject the line still appears in the screen. What's wrong with my code. Below is the script attach to gameobject to create a linerenderer.

```
public class CreateLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject myLine;
    LineRenderer lr;



    public void Start()
    {
        lr = new LineRenderer();
        ShapeCreator();
    }

    public void ShapeCreator()
    {
        lr = myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
        lr.positionCount = 3;
        lr.startWidth = .1f;
        lr.endWidth = .1f;
        lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(shapePositionValues.posA, 
        shapePositionValues.posD, -1));
        lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(shapePositionValues.posB, 
        shapePositionValues.posE, -1));

        lr.useWorldSpace = false;
        Gradient gradient = new Gradient();
        gradient.SetKeys(
        new GradientColorKey[]
            {
                new GradientColorKey(Color.Red, 100f)
            },
            new GradientAlphaKey[] {
                new GradientAlphaKey(1f, 0.0f)
            }
        );
        lr.colorGradient = gradient;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
The prefabs are destroyed but it leaves a gameobject. In the image below lineprefab is the prefab. Everytime I instantiate it spawn a lineprefab then a gameobject. My theory is that is the gameobject where a script is attach and made into prefab?

[image]

Comment: Well, your code shouldn't even work. 1) `public LineRenderer lr = new LineRenderer();` you can't call `new` on Components. 2) `GameObject myLine; myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();` your myLine variable here can never be anything other than null. So either you aren't showing us your actual code or it can't possibly do what you say. You also aren't destroying `myLine`.

Comment: @Draco18s Thank you sir for pointing it. I have update my codes to actual. Kindly check it again. I should destroy the prefab then the myLine variable? From what I understand when u destroy the prefab the script attached to it are also destroyed?

Comment: Now it shouldn't even compile because you don't declare `myLine` in the same scope that you use it.

Comment: @Draco18s I've fix the coding sir, sorry about that. Why does  the line still exist even I destroy it's prefab? Thanks

Comment: `GameObject lines... Destroy()...` where is this run in? In start, update, some other method?

Comment: @remy_rm In the update method here's the code.  void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer <= 0)
        {
GameObject lines = (GameObject)Instantiate(screenlines,new Vector3 ( 
    spawnerObjPos.transform.localPosition.x, listoflines[testt], 
    spawnerObjPos.transform.localPosition.z), transform.rotation);
Destroy(lines , 5);

timer = delayTimer;
}

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple things wrong with this script, and shouldn't even be able to compile.

Let's start off with the Awake method.

```
private void Awake()
{
    public LineRenderer lr = new LineRenderer();
    GameObject myLine;
}
```

Here you are trying to set an access modifier to the variable `lr` inside the local scope `Awake`, this isn't possible. you are also trying to   add a lineRenderer using `new LineRenderer`. This is not how you add Components in Unity.

The GameObject `myLine`, and LineRenderer `lr` you're creating here are only useable inside the `Awake` scope. Seeing it is created at the end of the scope means it isn't ever  used. You won't be able to access these variables from your `ShapeColor` method.

Instead you should get rid of the entire `Awake` function as it isn't doing anything right now, and replace it by declaring the variables in the class level scopes like so

```
public class CreateLine : MonoBehaviour
{
   GameObject myLine; //This is now not limited to the Awake scope, but useable through the entire script
   LineRenderer lr;

    public void Start()
    {
        ShapeCreator();
    }
    //Rest of code...
```

Then inside your `ShapeCreator` method we have the following:

```
public void ShapeCreator()
{
    lr = myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();

    //Rest of code....
}
```

You're trying to add the LineRenderer component to `myLine`, however as established earlier this does not exist due to `myLine` only existing in the local scope of `Awake`. After you have unscoped `myLine` as said above `myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();` will indeed work though, and add the LineRenderer to the GameObject. The same goes for the LineRenderer `lr`

`Destroy(lines , 5);` Should work just fine for destroying the gameobject, which in turn will destroy the linerenderer component which should get rid of the lines themselves

I'd also advice you to read up some information about "scopes" and how they work, aswel as looking at the console for errors, as the errors in there helps you debug these kind of issues.

The reason you keep seeing the lines is because you are creating the lines in an update loop, with a timer probably shorter than 5 seconds, but only destroying them after 5 seconds. This means that new lines will be instantiated continously *before*  you remove the old lines.

if you move it out of the update and into a method only called once (start, awake etc) you will see that it only instantiates one line, and removes this one line after 5 seconds, or increase the `timer` to be longer than 5 seconds.

Comment: Also, `myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();` already returns the component created, which marks the second line as obsolete. 
So that could also be changed to `lr = myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();`

Comment: Thank you for pointing the error in my code. Now I've fix that. My question is why the line still exist even I destroy it's prefab? Thanks

Comment: @remy_rm No errors. Before I destroy the prefab the line is moving after I destroy the prefab the line just stay in the screen. I forgot to tell you that the script attached to prefab inherits from other script. I've updated my post

Comment: @Newboy11 You are destroying the objects, just that you're waiting 5 seconds, during which time you continue to create more lines (one every frame).

Comment: @Draco18s I tried to instantiate just one prefab. It spawns a prefab then a gameobject after 5 seconds the prefab was destroyed but it's gameobject remains. Does creating a empty gameobject and attaching a script then make it a prefab cause this?

Comment: You have dozens of `New Game Object` entries in your hierarchy. The code you have shown cannot create those. You only have one (visible) `lineprefab (Clone)` object, so your MVCE does not appear to be Complete.

Comment: @Newboy11 I've edited my answer to include a final answer. It is because you run the instantiate in the update loop, meaning new lines will be created before the old one is deleted due to the 5 seconds delay. meaning there is always 1 or more line object active.

Comment: @remy_rm kindly check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for this. What I did is I created a empty gameobject and manually add linerender component not in script then create a prefab. Then in script I just called the linerenderer component using lr = GetComponent();. When Destroying that prefab no gameobject remains.